# JPA ElementCollection Map<Integer, Entity>

Tags: eclipselink, java-ee-7, jpa-2.1, glassfish-4.1

i need to assign the value of the map to my entity but jpa tries to save the hole object as an byte array.

```
@Entity
public class ImageSet {
    ...
    @ElementCollection
    private Map<Integer, Image> images = new LinkedHashMap<>();
}

@Entity
public class Image {
    ...
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
}
```

I think it is not that hard but i cant find any examples online. Could you please help me? thank you very much!

Comment: Not sure but don't you need to annotate the class as ```@Entity``` from ```javax.persistence.Entity```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Association annotated with `@ElementCollection` is valid for the following mapping types:

- `Map<Basic,Basic>`
- `Map<Basic,Embeddable>`
- `Map<Embeddable,Basic>`
- `Map<Embeddable,Embeddable>`
- `Map<Entity,Basic>`
- `Map<Entity,Embeddable>`

Association annotated with `@OneToMany` / `@ManyToMany` is valid for the following mapping types:

- `Map<Basic,Entity>` (this is your case)
- `Map<Embeddable,Entity>`
- `Map<Entity,Entity>`

---

According to the above rules the entities may look as follows:

```java
@Entity
public class ImageSet {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="container")
    @MapKey //map key is the primary key
    private Map<Integer, Image> images = new LinkedHashMap<>();
}

@Entity
public class Image {
    ...
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private ImageSet container;
}
```

Note that bidirectional association between `ImageSet.images` and `Image.container` is optional, but removing it would create an additional table in the database.